# Testcafe redirect with token

Tags: authentication, testing, automated-tests, token, testcafe

Im doing some automation in Testcafe, I arrive at the documentation of **Intercept HTTP Requests**, and **Create a Custom Request Hook**, my doubt is, can I send a header to a "get" that request the URL that I trying to navigate, I have the token but I don't know how to pass the header to the "get" that make the web-app.

Answer (score 1):

You can set additional header in the `onRequest` method of the `RequestHook`. Navigate to the following section with TestCafe examples: [Control HTTP Requests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/examples/#control-http-requests). The "Set a Custom Referrer" example shows how to set a custom `Referer` header for specified requests during tests.